# JQuery can't access elements created using DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, createelement

Good day! I have this code below that displays a table and it's working. I can display the table and its content. Here's the code:

```
     if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var x = 0;
        var table = document.getElementById("tblData");

        for(x=0; x<data.length; x++) {

          dataInstance = data[x].split('*');

          var row = document.createElement("tr");
          var td1 = document.createElement("td");
          var td2 = document.createElement("td");
          var td3 = document.createElement("td");
          var td4 = document.createElement("td");
          var td5 = document.createElement("td");
          var td6 = document.createElement("td");
          var td7 = document.createElement("td");;

          var cb = document.createElement('input');
          cb.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

          var tn1 = document.createTextNode(dataInstance[1]);
          var tn2 = document.createTextNode(dataInstance[2]);
          var tn3 = document.createTextNode(dataInstance[3]);
          var tn4 = document.createTextNode(dataInstance[4]);
          var tn5 = document.createTextNode(dataInstance[5]);
          var tn6 = document.createTextNode(dataInstance[6]);

          td1.appendChild(cb);
          td2.appendChild(tn1);
          td3.appendChild(tn2);
          td4.appendChild(tn3);
          td5.appendChild(tn4);
          td6.appendChild(tn5);
          td7.appendChild(tn6);

          row.appendChild(td1);
          row.appendChild(td2);
          row.appendChild(td3);
          row.appendChild(td4);
          row.appendChild(td5);
          row.appendChild(td6);
          row.appendChild(td7);

          table.appendChild(row);
        }
    }
```

But then, when I try putting up some colors alternately on my table using JQuery, it can't find the rows that were created using DOM. Only the table header of the table which is in my html code is filled with color. This is my JQuery code:

```
 $("#tblData tr:even").css("background-color", "pink");
 $("#tblData tr:odd").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Can you please help me? Thank you so much in advance! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use [CSS](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/nthchild.html) for this? `tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: pink } tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: yellow }`

Comment: I have considered that, but then I also have other codes that needs this kind of solution. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: when is this jQuery code running? Your code to add rows looks like it's added after an AJAX request is finished. That happens asynchronously. You need to ensure the jQuery code is running after that code completes.

Comment: color it after this line table.appendChild(row);

Comment: _I also have other codes that needs this kind of solution_ - The CSS is applied to every element matching the selector O.o The color will be changed for every table row in the document.

Comment: @Andreas I mean I have other codes that JQuery can't find dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is to run JQuery code after creating elements.